# How to run an insert script file in oracle with around 2.5 million insert statements?

Tags: sql, oracle, insert, bulk-operations

I have an insert script file in oracle with around 2.5 million insert statements. Idea needed to insert into Oracle table.

I have tried inserting using SQL Developer, by executing the file directly `@path\script.sql`.  But it times out.

Comment: 2,5million **individual** INSERT statements???  And you face timeout issues? Imagine!

Comment: Where did those insert statements come from? Presumably they weren't written by hand.

Comment: its an export , am trying to insert those records in another table.

Comment: When you say export, do you mean a data pump export, or some other format?

Answer (score 2):

2.5 million individual INSERT statements is always going to suck: you need to use something more suited for bulk data volume

> "its an export , am trying to insert those records in another table "

The best approach would be to redo the export in a different format, say using datadump.

Alternatively, as @thatjeffsmith suggests, you could export the records in CSV format and import them using SQL*Loader;

SQL Developer has options to help with this.

Comment: i would only suggest if they're a developer w/o access to the server/datapump, they could also try SQL*Loader

Answer (score 0):

As a last resort remove per script the  `INSERT` part of the statements and leave only the values in `csv` format.

Define an `EXTERNAL TABLE` or load it with `SQL*Loader`

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one-time script, spend a few minutes to manually group statements into anonymous PL/SQL blocks by adding multiple `BEGIN` and `END; /` to the file.  There's no need to use an alternative format or tool unless you are going to constantly regenerate this file.

Scripts with a large number of statements are usually slow because of network lag.  Each statement is sent to the server, executed, and returns a status.  Even when running on the same host, the communication overhead can still exceed the amount of time used to perform the real work.

PL/SQL blocks are sent to the server as a single unit.  If you send blocks of 100 statements at a time the network overhead will be reduced by 99%.  You won't see much improvement by using blocks of 1000, 10000, etc., but the larger the block the less manual editing you need to do.  But beware, if the block is *too* large it will exceed a compilation limit and throw an error.

Answer (score -1):

Under the assumption that those records are clean, you can disable logging and index on the tables you want to insert. Also i would do an commit after 1000 records or as per your demand.

Comment: Please test your approach with say 100.000 inserts and that review the advice.